Whether we can prove Error Reduction for $\textbf{RP}$ like $\textbf{BPP}$ or not?
I'm doing exercise 7.4 in Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach.

(Error Reduction for $\textbf{RP}$) Let $L\subseteq \{0, 1\}^∗$ be such that there exists a polynomial-time PTM $M$ satisfying for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^∗$: (1) If $x\in L$, then Pr[$M(x) = 1$] $\ge n^{−c}$ and (2) if $x\notin L$, then Pr[$M(x) = 1$] = $0$.
Prove that for every $d > 0$ there exists a polynomial-time PTM $M'$ such that for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^∗$, (1) if $x\in L$ then Pr[$M'(x) = 1$] $\ge 1 − 2^{−n}$ and (2) if $x\notin L$ then
Pr[$M'(x) = 1$] = $0$.

The common solution is that $M'(x)$ simulates $M(x)$ $k$ times then return OR of the results, where $k$ is a suitable polynomial of $|x|$.
However, I would like to do the exercise like the error reduction of $\textbf{BPP}$, i.e. $M'(x)$ simulates $M(x)$ $k$ times then return the major result. Let $X_i$ be the random variable denoting the $i$th execution of $M(x)$,$$X_i=\begin{cases}\text{1, if $M(x)=L(x)$},\\0, \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
If $\sum_{i\le k} X_i\ge k/2$, we will got the right answer. Let $p_i=\text{Pr[$X_i=1$]}$, we need to determine $p_i$ to complete the proof. My inference is \begin{align}p_i&=Pr[X_i=1|x\in L]\cdot Pr[x\in L]+Pr[X_i=1|x\notin L]\cdot Pr[x\notin L]\\&\ge n^{-c}\cdot 1/2+1\cdot 1/2,\end{align}
because I think that $\text{Pr[$x\in L$]=1/2}$. Then we use Chernoff bound to prove the remaining similarly $\textbf{BPP}$.
My question is if $\text{Pr[$x\in L$]=1/2}$ and $p_i$'s inference are correct? My intuition is that $L$ and $\bar{L}$ are countable sets, so $|L|=|\bar{L}|$.

This approach does not make sense. If the probability of a false negative is $1/2$, then in the case $x\in L$, you will get the correct result with probability $1/2$ regardless of how many repetitions you make, not with probability close to $1$. Worse, the requirements of the exercise do not stop at false negative probability $1/2$. You need to be able get the right answer with high probability when the false negative probability is $3/4$ or $.9999,$ or even approaches $1$ as a power law as $|x|\to \infty.$ In these cases,  a majority vote strategy is disastrous: it will cause you to get the wrong answer most of the time, with higher and higher probability as you repeat more and more.
Which is why, as you mention, the way to do it is to repeat some suitable number of times and then accept if you you ever get a positive result, and reject if you don't ever get one. This makes much more sense, since there is zero probability of false positives... if you want as low error rate as possible, you are logically obligated to accept if you ever see a positive result. It's a very different situation than BPP, where there's two-sided error but false positive/negative probabilities are bounded below $1/2.$ And in fact the error reduction calculation for RP is easier in the sense that only elementary probability (i.e. nothing like the Chernoff bound) is needed to compute the required number of repetitions.

Tks for your answer! I also thought that it should be computed $p_i$ in the cases $x\in L$ and $x\notin L$ separately. However, when $x\in L$, we can't utilize the one sized error fact. No advanced tools are needed in the problem as you say.

@minhquýlê Any strategy where you reject if you never see a positive result will have 100% accuracy in the $x\notin L$ case (the original machine produces no false positives). It’s the $x\in L$ side to worry about, where you may get false negatives and you may need to run many times to get your positive evidence if the false negative probability is high.
